# Issue with site and wave.webaim.org

Tags: joomla, accessibility

Hello I am sorry but I am a newbie. And i would like to help me out please to understand. I created a accessibility joomla site and have k2store. Everything works fine but when I add a product in the cart nothing happens(neither the pop up message nor the page). Instead i get a message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load url/index.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wave.webaim.org' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 406.
But this happens only in the validators. Live it works fine. Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use WAVE for your site, you have to use the wave toolbar: https://wave.webaim.org/toolbar/ which does not have that restriction.

WAVE online tool uses a proxied copy of your website because it uses Javascript to make its tests and their script have to be able to access your inner DOM.

Remote Javascript calls won't work as there are cross domain policy restrictions.

You could specifiy a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://wave.webaim.org` header but that would be a lot of work. Using the toolbar is definitely easier.

I should precise, to be complete, that you might also look at other online tools or toolbars in the following list:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/

Answer (score 1):

I am biased because I work on this product, but I would recommend the free and open source [aXe toolbar](http://www.deque.com/products/axe/) and its related JavaScript library for a bunch of reasons:

1. It has a rule set that produces almost 0 false positives
2. It has an [accompanying JavaScript library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axe-core) so you can run the same rule set in your Selenium or unit tests
3. The rule set is up-to-date with the latest ARIA techniques
4. It is the only tool that supports cross origin iframes